# convert all xlsx files in directory to txt with for loop

Tags: loops, libreoffice

I have a list of 150 `.xlsx` files in a directory that I am trying to convert to txt.  After all the files are converted I am going to combine each of the file (data only) to one large text file (all.txt), but the below command runs though the files remain as `.xlsx`.  Is this not the way to do this? Thank you :).

```
for i  in *.xlsx; do  libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt "$i" ; done
```

Comment: I also tried `--convert-to- csv` and the command runs but nothing happens.  Txt files are desired but I was trying another command as well.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but in `dos`:

```
Copy *.xlsx *.txt
```

did the trick.  Thank you :).